# NSManagedObject subclass conform to the <MKAnnotation> protocol?

Tags: iphone, core-data, mkannotation

My main problem is storing the data which is not supported by Core Data. I already have a CLLocation property stored as a transformable attribute. I think the right approach is to declare a transient coordinate property. I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors however.

EDIT:

My current subclass has the following interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface Event : NSManagedObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate* timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *location;

@end
```

So I need to add

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

and

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate;
```

to conform to the protocol. (setCoordinate is optional, but I need it if I want to have the annotation draggable)

In core data, The location property is transformable. and I use @dynamic in the implementation to generate the accessors. I'm using this property throughout the code, so I don't want to keep this.

I think the best way to go about it is to define my coordinate property in core data as transient, but I am not definitely doing something wrong with the implementation.

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cor = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.location.coordinate.latitude,
    self.location.coordinate.longitude);
    return cor;
}

- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {
    CLLocation *newLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newCoordinate.latitude
    longitude:newCoordinate.longitude];
    [self.location release];
    self.location = newLoc;
}
```

I've tried several ways, but this is the most recent one.

Edit 2:
The EXC_BAD_ACCESS in:

```
_kvcPropertysPrimitiveSetters
```

Comment: You really should supply more detail unless your just asking whether you can apply the protocol.

Comment: edited with more detail. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a NSManagedObject subclass conform to whatever protocol you wish as long as the protocol doesn't somehow override the context's management of the instances. MKAnnotation protocol should be perfectly safe.

Update:

Your problem is most likely here:

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {
    CLLocation *newLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newCoordinate.latitude
                                                    longitude:newCoordinate.longitude];
    [self.location release]; //<-- Don't release properties!
    self.location = newLoc;
}
```

The generator accessors will handle retention for you. When you release them directly you screw that management up. You're also leaking `newLoc`. Try:

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {
    CLLocation *newLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newCoordinate.latitude
                                                    longitude:newCoordinate.longitude];
    self.location = newLoc;
    [newLoc release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know where you are getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors, however here are a couple of ideas. First off, assuming that there is an outside class that wants to call `setCoordinate:` you should really change the `@property` to list `coordinate` as `readwrite` as you are teling the world they aren't allowed to change this value. The other thing you could try is to go ahead and actually sent `coordinate` in `setCoordinate:` then you can eliminate your custom `coordinate` method and allow Core Data to write you a faster one.

Comment: I have the readonly because Apple Docs say that it must be
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MKAnnotation/coordinate

also, I believe core data requires you to implement accessors yourself when the property is transient. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Looks like I missed some stuff regarding KVC with my current implementation.